# SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface is undefined

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine, game-development, vulkan

I am trying to create a Vulkan surface in C++ but I get this "identifier SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface is undefined" error. I use SDL with Vulkan and my source code looks like this:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

#include <iostream>

VkSurfaceKHR createVulkanSurface(SDL_Window* window, VkInstance instance) {
  VkSurfaceKHR surface;
  if (SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface(window, instance, &surface) != SDL_TRUE) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create Vulkan surface!");
  }
  return surface;
}
```

I am running the code in Debug x64 mode.

Another thing that I should mention is that I set up the project like this (at least for Debug x64) in the project configuration properties:

- C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> paths to SDL
  and VulkanSDK Include folders
- Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> paths to
  lib\x64 for SDL and Lib for VulkanSDK
- Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies ->
  opengl32.lib;SDL2.lib;SDL2main.lib;vulkan-1.lib


  That's pretty much it, I think. Let me know if there is something I did wrong here.Thank you for your attention :D

Comment: Do you get the same error for any other SDL function?

Comment: I think you need to include `SDL_vulkan.h` as well.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, for example, SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) worked.

Comment: @user7860670 is right. I needed to include SDL_vulkan.h. Looks like a rookie mistake by me. Thank you all :D